# mostrar lo que no está en uso en una tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo dos tablas , una se llama categories , la otra se llama ítems, entonces por ejemplo si agrego una hamburguesa en la tabla items y le agrego una categoría de la tabla categories  entonces este producto queda asociado a esa categoría, ahora bien  con el siguiente código muestro un una página todas las categorías que están en la tabla categories , sin importar si están asociadas o no a un producto

```
$db = Database::connect();
              $statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
              $categories = $statement->fetchAll();
              foreach ($categories as $category)
```

Hasta ahí todo bien , luego si remplazo ese código por este otro

```
$db = Database::connect();
                     $statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN categories ON items.category = categories.id ORDER BY items.id DESC');
                    $categories = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach ($categories as $category)
```

este me muestra las categorias que estan en uso , es decir las que están asociadas a un producto...hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo lo que deseo es mostrar solamente  aquellas categorías que no están asociadas a ningún producto, y en realidad no se que como hacerlo , si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Hola @BetaM , no comprendo

Comment: lo que deseo es mostrar solamente aquellas categorías que no están asociadas a ningún producto.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr de varias maneras y una podría ser más eficiente que otra, dependiendo de los índices en tus tablas.

Los dos métodos que podrían ser mejores son:

### 1. Combinar `LEFT JOIN` con `IS NULL`.

Se trataría de un `LEFT JOIN`, parecido a lo que tienes, pero poniendo un `WHERE` que verifique que el `id` es `NULL`, que es lo que ocurrirá en aquellas columnas que no tengan asociación con la tabla `items`. Esta consulta es más rápida si las columnas del `JOIN` están indexadas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
    LEFT JOIN items ON categories.id = items.category
WHERE categories.id IS NULL ORDER BY categories.id DESC;
```

Quizá sería más interesante ordenar por el nombre de categoría.

---

### 2. Usando `NOT IN()`

Otra forma de hacerlo sería con `NOT IN`, del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT category FROM items);
```

Esta consulta seleccionaría las filas de `categories` cuyo `id` no se encuentre en `items`.

---

Se podría usar también `NOT EXISTS()`, pero suele ser más lenta. Como dije, todo depende del contexto, de los índices que haya en tus tablas, **y también de las columnas que selecciones**, etc. Para fines de optimización conviene siempre hacer pruebas y quedarte con la mejor opción. Sin olvidar poner en el `SELECT` de forma explícita, **únicamente aquellas columnas que necesites**, evitando en todo momento el uso de `SELECT *`.

Para más detalles sobre las diferencias, puedes consultar [este interesante artículo](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Comment: Para mejorar el rendimiento de la consulta en la segunda opción,  podrías agregar `DISTINCT` en la sub consulta, es decir, `SELECT DISTINCT categoría...`

Comment: Mil gracias  nos funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = Database::connect();
    $statement = $db->query('
    SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    FROM categories
    WHERE items.category = categories.id 
    ORDER BY items.id DESC');
                  $categories = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Haber si le ayuda este fragmento, pero para ver resultado tiene que tener al menos en la tabla items algunos records vacios en la columna category, pruebe y me avisa.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. Si bien la respuesta, es posible que sea válida, no se adecúa a lo requerido por el sitio. Podrías al menos, comentar el motivo, por el cuál la solución es la apropiada y así quien pregunta y otros que puedan leer la misma, pueden aprender de ella.

Comment: Grande Tonny grande